# convert php regex to java regex

Tags: java, php, regex

Can somebody help me with converting a php regex to java regex?

It would be great and I would be appreciate you if you can help me, because I'm not so strong in regex.

```
$str = preg_replace ( '{(.)\1+}', '$1', $str )
$str = preg_replace ( '{[ \'-_\(\)]}', '', $str )
```

How I understand `preg_replace` function in php is the same as `replaceAll` in java?..
So in java code it would be like this.

```
str = str.replaceAll("{(.)\1+}", "$1");
str = str.replaceAll("{[ \'-_\(\)]}", "");
```

But this code wont be work because how I know that regex in php is different by java.

Please, somebody help me! Thanks a lot))

**update**

final result is

```
str = str.replaceAll("(.)\\1+", "$1");
str = str.replaceAll("[ '-_()]", "");
```

Comment: Don't escape more than you need to. Your second pattern could just as well be `[ '-_()]` (although in PHP you'd still have to escape the `'`, of course).

Comment: If you're not using any non-core regex features, regexes are the same everywhere and the only thing to look out for is stuff like whether you need to double up (escape) backslashes or not, multi-line behaviour, etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this PHP regex:

```
$str = preg_replace ( '{(.)\1+}', '$1', $str );
$str = preg_replace ( '{[ \'-_\(\)]}', '', $str )
```

In Java:

```
str = str.replaceAll("(.)\\1+", "$1");
str = str.replaceAll("[ '-_\\(\\)]", "");
```

I suggest you to provide your input and expected output then you will get better answers on how it can be done in PHP and/or Java.

Comment: Thanks!)) Yep! Surely I add the example of input string when I would be know it. At this time I don't know what is it)

Answer (score 2):

The only difference with Java regex is that you have to escape the backslashes.

```
str = str.replaceAll("(.)\\1+", "replacerString");
str = str.replaceAll("[ \\'-_\\(\\)]", "");
```